# update an object's foreign key value with LINQ to Entities

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

I have two tables:

```
Product
 - ProdID       INT PK
 - ProdName     NVARCHAR(30)

Service
 - ServiceID      INT PK
 - ProdServiceID  INT FK: Product
 - ServiceName    NVARCHAR(30)
```

How do I update the ProdServiceID in the database using LINQ to entities?
I am using VB

Thanks!

BB

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just assign a new value to the ProdServiceID property in your code and call context.SaveChanges()? If your model is defined correctly this should result in updating the database accordingly.